# How to Create two side by side plots from a subset of data in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I have a large data frame that is essentially divided based on year (i.e there is data from 2004 and 2005) and I am hoping to create two side by side histograms with the data from 2004 and 2005.

I have already created a histogram with the data from both years, but I am having trouble separating it based on the year.

```
library(ggplot2)
NextRatings <- read.csv("DataSet.csv", header = TRUE)

line <- ggplot(NextRatings, aes(x=rating.avg)) + 
           geom_histogram(aes (y = ..density..), binwidth = .5, colour = "black", fill = "white") + 
           geom_density(alpha = .2, colour = "blue")
```

This is the code that produces the histogram from both years, but I do not know how to separate them into two histograms based on year.

Comment: Please create a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by providing some example data with `dput`

Answer (score 1):

The function you are looking for is `facet_wrap`

Create some dummy data:

```
NextRatings <- data.frame(year = rep(c(2001, 2019), 500),
                          rating.avg=rnorm(500))

line <- ggplot(NextRatings, aes(x=rating.avg)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes (y = ..density..), binwidth = .5, 
                 colour = "black", fill = "white") + 
  geom_density(alpha = .2, colour = "blue") + 
  facet_wrap("year")
line
```

[image]